# Not able to start x11 on suse

Tags: x11

Hi I am not able to start x11 dispaly on suse 12 . This is the error message I am getting

xauth:  file /export/home/gtee/.serverauth.16595 does not exist

(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot open log file "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE)
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable

### xinit: server error

xinit failed. /usr/bin/Xorg is not setuid, maybe that's the reason?
If so either use a display manager (strongly recommended) or adjust /etc/permissions.local

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be related to software development.  Perhaps try [Super User](https://superuser.com/) ?